# Correlation of levels vs. differences vs. percents

Tags: correlation, data-transformation, interpretation, normalization

Sometimes, I have seen people using correlation of levels, correlation of differences and also correlation of percent changes.

I understand these answer different questions. For example, for "what is the correlation between shoes and T-shirt quantities", one would use levels (perhaps after standardizing). For "what is the correlation between the growth rates of shoes and T-shirts", one would use percent changes. For what question would you use the correlation in differences?

```
Q(shoes)    Q(T-shirts)     delta(shoes)    delta(T-shirts) pct_change(shoes)   pct_change(T-shirts)
1000005     34              
1000342     36              337             2               0%                  6%
1000842     32              500             -4              0%                  -11%
1000042     42              -800            10              0%                  31%
1000122     40              80              -2              0%              -   5%
1000432     51              310             11              0%                  28%
1000932     58              500             7               0%                  14%
```

Further, I know that you could log your data if it follows an exponential pattern. Then you would find the correlation of the two series using this logged data. This is normalizing the data, which I believe is different from what is being done above (ie. simple transformations).

What is the terminology distinction here? For example, square rooting or logging your data is 'normalization', but converting it to differences or percents is not (I believe). After normalizing, can you still transform the data? (eg. differences of logs would effectively give you percent changes, but are there other transformations to consider?)

To reiterate my questions, when would you use correlation of differences? Are there any other 'transformations' (like converting to percents) that I am missing, but are also useful to consider? This question is not really about methods for normalization (because I suspect I will mostly rely on Box-Cox transformations).

Answer (score 1):

In Finance and economics all three are used a lot for different purposes. For instance, if you have series of asset prices $p_i$, then you can create series of simple returns $r_i=\frac{p_i}{p_{i-1}}-1$ or log returns $r_i=\ln p_i-\ln p_{i-1}$

The price series are usually non-stationary, that's why the correlation between them is usually nonsensical. You look at the correlation of returns. You can also look at the changes: $\Delta p_i= p_i- p_{i-1}$.

The price to return conversion is a data transformation. You can apply further transformations, of course.